# How to fix error "Unable to instantiate service *<*.TimerIntentService> has no zero argument constructor"

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-intentservice

I am setting up timer as a feature in my android application. App is based on fragments. It has just two activities and a lot of fragments, connected by navigation.

I try implement timer using Intent service, but I have problem. App crashes on button click.

I tried to put some data to Intent service and there i want to implement timer.

Timer starts from zero until user press "Pause".

TimerFragment.kt

```
class TimerFragment : ViewModelFragment<TimerViewModel>() {

    val TAG = "TimerFragment"

    override fun getLayoutResId() = R.layout.fragment_timer
    override fun getViewModelClass() = TimerViewModel::class

    lateinit var intent:Intent
    lateinit var pendingIntent:PendingIntent
    var mTimerRunning:Boolean = false

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        btn_manage_timer.setOnClickListener(object:View.OnClickListener{
            override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
                // y = start time (time that is on screen)
                manageTimer(p0!!,0)
            }
        })
    }

    private fun manageTimer(view: View, y:Int) {
        if (!mTimerRunning) {
            mTimerRunning = true

            intent = Intent(this.activity, TimerIntentService::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("startTime", y)
            intent.putExtra("mTimerRunning", mTimerRunning)
            this.activity!!.startService(intent)

            Toast.makeText(this.activity, "ALARM ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            btn_manage_timer.text = "Pause"
        }else{
            mTimerRunning = false

            intent.putExtra("startTime", y)
            intent.putExtra("mTimerRunning", mTimerRunning)

            btn_manage_timer.text = "Start"
        }
        return
    }
}
```

---

TimerIntentService.kt

```
class TimerIntentService(name: String) : IntentService(name) {

    private val TAG = "TimerIntentService"

    public constructor(context: Context) : this("TimerIntentService"){

    }

    override fun onHandleIntent(p0: Intent?) {
        Log.i(TAG,"onHandleIntent, Thread name ${Thread.currentThread()}")
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        Log.i(TAG,"onDestroy, Thread name ${Thread.currentThread()}")
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Log.i(TAG,"onCreate, Thread name ${Thread.currentThread()}")
    }
}
```

---

This is the full error:

```
2019-09-07 13:08:02.944 8988-8988/* E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: *, PID: 8988
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service *.sync.TimerIntentService: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<*.sync.TimerIntentService> has no zero argument constructor
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3940)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1875)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<*.sync.TimerIntentService> has no zero argument constructor
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateService(AppComponentFactory.java:129)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateService(CoreComponentFactory.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3935)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:219) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1875) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Answer (score -1):

In your concrete implementation you have to declare a default constructor.

**Replace :**

```
class TimerIntentService(name: String) : IntentService(name)

public constructor(context: Context) : this("TimerIntentService"){  }
```

**With :**

```
class TimerIntentService : IntentService

constructor() : super(null){ }
```

Thats all.